# What are valid usages of suggest?

Tags: verbs

Could anyone clarify once and for all the usage of *suggest*?

All the grammars I have consulted allow for only four possibilities:

- *Suggest* + ing form
- *Suggest that* + direct object + *should* + bare infinitive
- *Suggest that* + direct object + bare infinitive
- *Suggest that* + direct object + simple past

They all say that *suggest* must never be followed by an indirect object.

However, I keep finding sentences that seem to contradict these rules:

> "We suggested to the committee that they review the case again." (Merriam-Webster online dictionary."
>
> "Can you suggest to them that Company Name develop the Italian version of the website?" (this website's thread of some months ago)

to mention only a few.

Could anybody please help?

Comment: Change your second possibility to allow *should* to be optional, and to allow optional *to + indirect object* before *that*; those two modifications would take care of the two possibilities you mention. *Should* is pretty flexible; I'm not sure that its usage can be clarified **once and for all** without going on and on and on.

Comment: Thank you. So, are you suggesting to me that I set my mind at rest?

Answer (score 2):

You can put the indirect object before or after the direct object as long as  which is which is indicated as necessary by means of a preposition. "I proposed/suggested/gave Daniel TO the lions. " or "I proposed/suggested/gave TO Daniel the lions."    I think we would tend to put the shorter of the two first, eg.  "The apple gave to Newton the idea of a generalised operating force which blah blah ... " rather than "The apple gave  the idea of a generalised operating force which blah blah... to Newton ".  but "The apple suggested gravity to the scientist who was sitting under a tree while blah blah..."

Comment: Thank you. My problem is not the indirect or direct object but the construction of suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start with the bottom line:

**When a dictionary like Merriam Webster tells you something, do it, if you don't want so waste time.** Especially at your level. And assume that you just haven't read enough grammar books, sorry.

For you haven't. A cursory search at Google Books for:

[**"suggests to them that" grammar**](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22suggests%20to%20them%20that%22%20grammar&hl=en&tbm=bks&start=0&ei=ICYkVenRB6q1sQS24YHYBw)

shows these books that clearly are written by experts in grammar, books that contain one of the cores under discussion:

> [Word-Order Change as a Source of Grammaticalisation](https://books.google.ca/books?id=PVQzAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA95&dq=%22suggests%20to%20them%20that%22%20grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7SAkVfDYC5HLsATx9oHYBw&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22suggests%20to%20them%20that%22%20grammar&f=false) - Page 95 Susann
>   Fischer - 2010 -
>
> The fact that (18) is ungrammatical **suggests to them that** the
>   presence of a subject gap cannot be an ...
>
> __
>
> [Issues and options in language teaching](https://books.google.ca/books?id=2K4lAQAAIAAJ&q=%22suggests%20to%20them%20that%22%20grammar&dq=%22suggests%20to%20them%20that%22%20grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4yEkVa7cAqLnsAT16YHgBw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA) - Page 142 Hans Heinrich
>   Stern, ‎John Patrick Brierley Allen, ‎Birgit Harley - 1992
>
> They acknowledge that there is an important aspect of second language
>   acquisition which cannot be influenced by grammatical analysis. Yet,
>   practical experience **suggests to them that** one cannot entirely do
>   without overt grammar teaching

__

> [A Unified Theory of Syntactic Categories](https://books.google.ca/books?id=x6hdpjVvnegC&pg=PA7&dq=%22suggests%20to%20them%20that%22%20grammar&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1iIkVYn4KObgsASOmYLgBw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22suggests%20to%20them%20that%22%20grammar&f=false)- Page 7 Joseph E. Emonds -
>   1985
>
> ... COMP and INFL, analogous to an agreement between SP(N) and N,
>   which **suggests to them that** COMP = SP(INFL).

Do you really think experts like these would be caught writing bad English?

Also, along the same lines, in a  [grammar forum](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/589109012).

And this is coded in the grammar bible of **Quirk et al, A comprehensive grammar of the the english language**, 16-60, p. 1214, as [D3pr] verbs, as well as here:

> [English Ditransitive Verbs: Aspects of Theory, Description and a
>   Usage-based ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=82PkSglvI8MC&pg=PA13&dq=d3pr+verbs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fC8kVe2lKPGwsASHr4DICA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=d3pr%20verbs&f=false)  By Joybrato Mukherjee
>
> In particular, the special subcategory [D3pr] should be mentioned in
>   which the ditransitive verb is said to be complemented with a
>   prepositional ...

So, perhaps you'll get Quirk et al now :-) Now, that's a real grammar.

Comment: Thank you. The examples you mention, however, seem to imply a meaning of 'suggest' different from 'recommend' or 'advise.'    Would you still suggest to me that I get Quirk at al?

Comment: It's an expensive, large book (2,000 pages), extremely well written and reasoned. If you are really passionate about grammar, yes, but it's going to take you 1-2 years to read it. If you don't plan to make that effort, better not. Perhaps you have an university library close by that has it.

Comment: Also, try  http://goo.gl/I9b8WM where some of the people responding know it.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't actually mean to buy the book (I'm not that passionate about grammar). I was just trying to apply the rule ... well, it works!