# Use of subjunctive after "suggested"

Tags: subjunctive-mood

1. Australian children's book author Mem Fox has suggested **she might never to return to the US** after she was detained and insulted by border control agents at Los Angeles airport.

So far as I know, after a suggestion the subjunctive or infinitive is used. But here, "she might never to return to the US" is neither one. Should it be

2. Australian children's book author Mem Fox has suggested **never to
   return to the US** after she was detained and insulted by border
   control agents at Los Angeles airport.
   Or,
3. Australian children's book author Mem Fox has suggested **that she never
   return to the US** after she was detained and insulted by border
   control agents at Los Angeles airport.

Which of these sentences are correct, if any? What would be the correct way to say this?

Comment: #1 is fine. #2 looks too strong to be a *suggestion*; it might be suitable phrasing for a *declaration*. #3 makes Mem Fox sound like she's making a snide remark concerning someone else. Can you link to the wording of the comment about suggestions, subjunctives and infinitives?

Comment: why 1 is fine?'she might never to return'-is it grammatically right?

Comment: You are correct; it is ungrammatical. The **to** does not belong in there.

Comment: They are all wrong. Apart from anything else, this use of "suggest" is not subjunctive (compare the genuine subjunctive I suggest you get your hair cut). And, they are grammatically wrong and/or make no sense. For example in 1, the modal "might" requires a bare infinitival complement so it should be ... suggested she might never return. Btw, "might" cannot occur in subjunctives since it has no plain (infinitival) form.

Comment: @user222273 [Sorry](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375433/use-of-subjunctive-after-suggested?noredirect=1#comment880132_375433), I missed the first *to*. It would be ok if it was "... she might never return to the US ...".

Comment: I'm still wondering where you got the impression that *suggestion* necessarily pairs with the subjunctive / an infinitive.

Comment: _Mem Fox has suggested she might never return to the US_ is not a subjunctive for two reasons: First, the subjunctive invokes the concept of 'compliance' as in, for example, _I suggest you never return to the US_. But the original is simply a declarative clause where Mem Fox is putting forward the proposition that she might not return to the US. Second, the modal "might" does not have an infinitival form, so it cannot occur in  subjunctive clauses.

Comment: I'm not sure what issue people are finding with the first sentence. It is quite clear to me. Perhaps the bolded part it should be preceded by a "that" although "that"s are often implied. The second and third sentences would mean different things even if grammatically correct.  If nothing else they are vague and could mean that the person is suggesting what other people should do, not her personal reaction. It is more like "I suggested that I might never be able to lose weight" , vs I suggested "never to lose weight" ... clearly the second means something different than the first.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/238011

Comment: @Tom22 The trouble with the first one is that it was misquoted. An extra word was added: “Australian children's book author Mem Fox has suggested she might never ***to*** return to the US”. _Might never to return_ is not grammatical (though of course it's still plain what is meant). Take away that extra _to_ and it's fine.

Answer (score 5):

The original sentence, which appears as the first sentence of [this Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/feb/25/australian-childrens-author-mem-fox-detained-by-us-border-control-i-sobbed-like-a-baby), is:

> Australian children's book author Mem Fox has suggested she might never return to the US after she was detained and insulted by border control agents at Los Angeles airport.

---

The subjunctive is very often used—especially in American English—in content clauses which convey the desired outcome of some explicit or implicit command or recommendation:

- We recommend [she be exonerated].

Notice that the subjunctive requires the plain form of the verb *BE* here, instead of present tense *is*. These types of sentence are often called *mandative* constructions, where the term *mandative* indicates 'conveying a command'.

The verb *SUGGEST* can be used in such a way. In other words we can use a content clause after the verb *SUGGEST* to indicate some desired outcome that is being being put forward by the suggester. In such a case we can use a subjunctive construction in the clause following the verb:

- We suggest [she be released immediately].

However, the verb *SUGGEST* can also have a very different meaning. It can mean, as described in the [MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/suggest):

> **3 to say that something is likely to exist or to be true**
>
> > *The cause of the problem, as Hutton suggests, is the leadership’s refusal to accept any form of criticism.*
> >
> > suggest (that): *Are you seriously suggesting she did this on purpose?*
> >
> > suggest (that): *I’m not suggesting that giving up smoking will be easy.*

When we use *suggest* with this meaning, the following clause does not indicate some desired outcome. Rather it describes something that the speaker is hinting might be true or become true. Very often this can be something **un**desirable, something we most definitely **don't** recommend or want to be true. For example:

- He suggested [that I was going to fail my exam].

When *suggest* is being used with this meaning, we cannot use a mandative construction. There is no reason for us to use a subjunctive, because the subordinate clause does not represent the desired outcome of a command or recommendation. Consider the following example:

- I suggest that Trump might be impeached before the next election.

In the sentence above, I am saying that I think it is a possibility that Trump will be impeached before the next election. I cannot use a subjunctive clause to try and convey this same meaning. If I do use a subjunctive clause after the verb *SUGGEST* here, then it will radically change the meaning. It will indicate that I am recommending or desiring the impeachment of Trump:

- I suggest that Trump be impeached before the next election.

This is not the meaning of my original sentence!

**The Original Poster's example**

> Australian children's book author Mem Fox has **suggested [she might never return to the US**] after she was detained and insulted by border control agents at Los Angeles airport.

Here Mem Fox is not saying that she is putting forward as a recommendation that she shouldn't return to the US. Instead she is implying that it might already be the case that she will never return to the US. She has already made the decision. Because she is not recommending any course of action here, we see a normal clause using the tensed modal verb *might* after the verb *SUGGEST*. A subjunctive construction would not be appropriate here and would change the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Sentence (1) is wrong because of the "to" before "return". The modal auxiliary "might" should be followed by a bare infinitive, not a to-infinitive. This might just be a typo.

This use of "suggest" doesn't actually indicate a suggestion. Its meaning is more like "insinuate". The subjunctive structure of (3) ("that she never return") is therefore in my view inappropriate. I can use a "mandative subjunctive" after "suggest" only for real suggestions, where someone is recommending a course of action to someone else. The American Heritage Dictionary gives as the second definition for *[suggest](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=suggest)*

> To express or say indirectly: *The police officer seemed to be suggesting that the death was not an accident.*

This sentence likewise cannot be rephrased as *"The police officer seemed to be suggesting that the death not be an accident."

Sentence (2) is not correct, though I'm not quite sure how to explain why. 
People don't really use "suggest to [infinitive]"; as Janus Bahs Jacquet points out in the comments, the usual structure is "suggest [gerund]" and this only works with recommendations for other people's actions, not descriptions of one's own actions. (The infinitive is used in the passive construction "be suggested to [inf]".)

In general, English is less tolerant of this kind of use of the infinitive (as a substitute for a relative clause with a subject that is the same as the subject of the main clause) than some other European languages such as French (another example that seems similar to me: in English it's not possible to say "I think to want..." in place of "I think that I want...").

A grammatically correct start to the sentence would be

> Australian children's book author Mem Fox **has suggested (that) she might never return** to the US...

Since this uses the perfect, I don't think putting the second part in the simple past tense sounds good. I would finish with a gerund clause instead:

> Australian children's book author Mem Fox **has suggested she might never return** to the US **after being** detained and insulted by border control agents at Los Angeles airport.

If I were to use the simple past tense in the second part, I would also use the simple past rather than the perfect in the first part:

> Australian children's book author Mem Fox **suggested she might never return** to the US **after she was** detained and insulted by border control agents at Los Angeles airport.

Comment: I agree. This use of "suggest" is not subjunctive (compare the genuine mandative _I suggest you go and see a doctor_) and of course "might" has no infinitival form so it cannot occur in subjunctives.

Comment: Whereas _suggest_ does not work with infinitival complements (at least I can't come up with any cases where it does, either), it does work fine with gerunds (in the ‘recommending a course of action’ sense): “She suggested **never returning** to the US”.

Comment: Actually, reading more closely, it seems you're saying that _suggest_ + _to_-infinitive is fine if the subjects are different. So you would consider “She suggested [him?] to never return” grammatical? I don't think that works in my world at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I think a to-infinitive may be possible after "suggest" in some circumstances, but not in general. I didn't say anything because I'm not sure what the exact circumstances are where it could work. The example in the following book doesn't sound too terrible to me, although a gerund sounds better in my opinion: https://books.google.com/books?id=1qKQBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA37&dq=%22suggested+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHvY2h7qvSAhUM_4MKHZEwCss4MhDoAQhMMAk#v=onepage&q=%22suggested%20to%22&f=false

Comment: Other examples: https://books.google.com/books?id=DK7GQFj8fvgC&pg=PA28&dq=%22suggested+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZm5W27qvSAhVJwYMKHUmyBeQ4PBDoAQgwMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22suggested%20to%22&f=false, https://books.google.com/books?id=EfB8OeyroEMC&pg=PA271&dq=%22suggested+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZm5W27qvSAhVJwYMKHUmyBeQ4PBDoAQhGMAg#v=onepage&q=%22suggested%20to%22&f=false these might just be errors, but they do exist somehow. Infinitives also are possible with the passive "be suggested (to INF)".

Comment: @sumelic Oops, I misread their example. You're quite right there ...

Comment: Have deleted my comments about the edit.

Answer (score 0):

After "suggested", we could have either a complement like that in the first of the the examples (but without the first "to", which is ungrammatical):

```
 (1) ... suggested [S she might never return to the US ]
```

or a complement like this:

```
 (2) ... suggested [S her fans never visit the US ]
```

However, if we try conjoining the complements, the result is ungrammatical.

```
 (3) *... suggested she might never return to the US and her fans never visit the US
```

Although I began by assuming that "suggested" was followed in both of my first two examples (1) and (2) by complements of category S, the ungrammaticality of the result of conjoining the two complements suggests to me that they are actually of different categories, because when you conjoin two constituents of the same category, you should get a grammatical constituent of that same category.

One way to resolve the difficulty would be to make the category of the complement in (2) above something different from S -- perhaps "subjunctive S".

Comment: Or there could just be a semantic problem there. *Suggest* has two different meanings in relation to the two complement clauses there and the internal grammar of each clause is incompatible with the semantics of the other meaning of *suggest* ....

Comment: In BE at least, I'm sure you could have "We recommend that she return home immediately and that she is allowed free passage at all international airports". So, if the first clause there isn't an S then wouldn't that prevent the second from being an S too? (even though it certainly looks like one)

Comment: @Araucaria, Yes, I would expect some interpretive  difference between "suggest" with an indicative complement and "suggest" that goes with a subjunctive complement.  Where does that get us?  To your second comment, yes, I agree.  Personally, I would like "... and that she be allowed free passage ..." much better.

Comment: Yes, I like that better too. Not sure where it gets us! Was just playing with your idea ...

Comment: I suggest you use the more common formatting.  The gray background bothers my eyes and makes it impossible for me to read your answer.